# Spring AOP pointcut expression syntax for wildcard

Tags: spring, aop, pointcut

I'm currently using AspectJ 1.6.9 and i wonder why the following pointcut expression:

```
(execution (* it.dtt..endpoint.*..*.invoke*(..)))
```

doesn't match the execution of the method declared:

```
protected Object invokeInternal(Object object) throws Exception
```

of the class:

```
it.dtt.prova.endpoint.Richiesta
```

any idea?

Comment: The fact that that method is named `invokeInternal` should be  trigger. It is probably invoked internally and internal method calls don't apply for AOP.

Answer (score 2):

"Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring's AOP , `protected` methods are by définition not intercepted".

you need to change the access modifier of that method to `public` or consider use the `spring-driven native AspectJ weaving`

[Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn):

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring's AOP framework, protected
>   methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies
>   (where this isn't applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is
>   technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes). As a
>   consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods
>   only!
>
> If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even
>   constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving
>   instead of Spring's proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a
>   different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure
>   to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.

Comment: True. If you need to intercept protected or private methods or use more powerful AOP tools like intercepting member access etc., you can always use full AspectJ from within Spring.